# Find a limit of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}$

It seems quite easy, but the problem is that I cannot find a dominating function when $x>1$

Comment: As an aside, for $0<k<n$ and $a>0$ we have $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{a^n+x^n}~dx~=~a^{k-n}~\frac\pi n~\csc\bigg(k~\frac\pi n\bigg)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 &: 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
\frac{1}{1+x^2} &: x > 1
\end{cases}
$$
For $n\geq 3$, each integrand is dominated by $g$.

Comment: But what about $n=1$? Shouldn't it be a dominating function for each $n$? I know it is a limit, but still...

Comment: You only care about the limit right? So you can ignore finitely many terms.

Comment: @Prold The constant function $1$ is not in $L^1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
is a dominating function when $x >1$.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to find a dominating function; alternatively you can notice that if $x > 1$ then $\frac 1{1+x^n}$ tends uniformily to $0$, so you can exchange the limit and the integral for $x > 1$